# Counting a String within a string

Tags: c++, string, counting

I'm told to ask the user for a string ( a sentence). Then the user is asked to input another string to search in string 1 (the sentence). The program has to count the number of times the second string shows up in the first string. I'm not getting any errors but it's is not counting the letters. This is the result i get:

**Enter a sentence:i love to eat soup**

**Enter string to search: ou**

**There are 0 of the string ou in the first string you provided.**

Can someone please tell me what i'm doing wrong? I'm a beginner at c++ so i'm having some trouble understanding.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int  main() {

        string sentence;
        string search;
        int count = 0;

        cout<<"Enter a sentence:";
        getline (cin, sentence);
        cout<<"Enter string to search:";
        getline (cin, search);

        cout << "There are " << count << " of the string " << search << " in the first string you provided." <<"\n";

        for (int i=0; i < sentence.size(); ++i)
        {
                if (sentence == search)

                count++;
        }

        return count;


}
```

Comment: Your for loop doesn't do anything.

Comment: Well, I think it's pretty clear.  There is a bug in your code!  1.  why do you suppose you can output the correct count before actually counting?  how do you think just == will let you look inside the string?

Answer (score 2):

Two issues:

1. You print `count` before you calculate it.
2. You are not actually searching for a substring. You should look at the documentation for [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) to find an appropriate way to search for substrings. However, you are on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're trying to output the results before calculating them.

Also, `==` is for *exact matches*, not substring searches.

Answer (score 0):

You have your cout print line after the loop where you search for the string and set the count.  Move it below that loop.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you should put the cout statement in the end of this method. Because in your code, count is always 0 when you output it

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your loop so that it *really* searches for substrings and count their occurrences:

```
string::size_type pos = sentence.find(search);
while (pos != string::npos)
{
    pos = sentence.find(search, pos + search.size());
    count++;
}
```

Also, you most likely want to move this line *after* the point where you actually compute the value of `count`:

```
cout << "There are " << count << ...
```

Otherwise, it will obviously output the value to which `count` was initialized originally (i.e. `0`).